# Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I had the same problem that in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path) and I applied what's recommended in the answers but what I got is another error.

This is the python script `functional_test.py`

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://localhost:8000')

assert 'Django' in browser.title
```

And this is the error that I get:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Hugo:Code hvillalobos$ python3 functional_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "functional_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    browser=webdriver.Firefox()File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 142, in __init__

    self.service.start()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
line 74, in start
stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: what's in functional_test.py?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question to show it.

Comment: Thank  you very much @demouser123